# Validation of a string Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, string, validation

I am using Spring Boot and I want to validate an email. In my DTO I have the field

```
@NotBlank
@Email
@Length(min = 5, max = 100)
String email
```

Now I want to validate, that for example the email does not contain subline `"@domain.com"`.
I can create my own annotation for validation, that is not a problem. But maybe there are already developed solutions about String format?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in answer above, you can use regex,`@Email` annotation accepts regexp as argument.

In your specific case, to validate that email doesn't contain string `@domain.com` you can use following regex:

```
 @Email(regexp ="^((?!@domain.com).)*$")
    @NotBlank
    @Length(min = 5, max = 100)
    String email;
```

Comment: thank you very much, I just started to get with regex, I had misunderstanding about this topic before.

Comment: that means, that another message about incorrect email is not shown. I created a new annotation a customed it as I wanted. The Pattern format and regex - something, I do not understand regex.

Answer (score 1):

Java Validation APIs provide a `@Pattern` annotation which accepts a regex:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html